# Set name in json format in php/laravel

Tags: php, arrays, json

How to set name to JSON object in laravel as I want to display for a plugin in Vue js for image gallery. Whenever I pass data I Got this error : Expected Object, got Array.

```
{
  "normal_size": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "image": "MICMIMC30651-6.jpg",
      "url": "http://localhost:8000/images/product/preview/MICMIMC30651-6.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "image": "MICMIMC30651-61.jpg",
      "url": "http://localhost:8000/images/product/preview/MICMIMC30651-61.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "image": "MICMIMC30651-62.jpg",
      "url": "http://localhost:8000/images/product/preview/MICMIMC30651-62.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "image": "MICMIMC30651-63.jpg",
      "url": "http://localhost:8000/images/product/preview/MICMIMC30651-63.jpg"
    }
  ]

}
```

```
output I wanted :
```

```
image : {
  "normal_size": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "image": "MICMIMC30651-6.jpg",
      "url": "http://localhost:8000/images/product/preview/MICMIMC30651-6.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "image": "MICMIMC30651-61.jpg",
      "url": "http://localhost:8000/images/product/preview/MICMIMC30651-61.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "image": "MICMIMC30651-62.jpg",
      "url": "http://localhost:8000/images/product/preview/MICMIMC30651-62.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "image": "MICMIMC30651-63.jpg",
      "url": "http://localhost:8000/images/product/preview/MICMIMC30651-63.jpg"
    }
  ]

}
```

`

### Laravel product controller code to pass data to vue component

```
 $normal_size = DB::table('products_images')->where([['products_id', '=', $product]])
        ->select('products_images.id','products_images.image')
        ->get()->ToArray();

foreach($normal_size as $value)
        {
            $value->url = 'http://localhost:8000/images/product/preview/'.$value->image;
        }
$output = (array('normal_size' => $normal_size));
return response()->json(($output));
```

Comment: Your "wanted" isn't valid JSON. Also, given we don't know your code, we can't definitively tell you how to get `image` unless you show us.

Comment: I think you are getting this data using json_encode, So at the time of json_encode add the required array with image as key. like $final_array['image'] = $array_data. json_encode($final_array);

Comment: I have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

[**Decode**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) your JSON to convert an array. Format the array structure you want and [**encode**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) the array to JSON.

```
$data = '{
  "normal_size": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "image": "MICMIMC30651-6.jpg",
      "url": "http://localhost:8000/images/product/preview/MICMIMC30651-6.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "image": "MICMIMC30651-61.jpg",
      "url": "http://localhost:8000/images/product/preview/MICMIMC30651-61.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "image": "MICMIMC30651-62.jpg",
      "url": "http://localhost:8000/images/product/preview/MICMIMC30651-62.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "image": "MICMIMC30651-63.jpg",
      "url": "http://localhost:8000/images/product/preview/MICMIMC30651-63.jpg"
    }
  ]
}';

$output = json_encode(['image' => json_decode($data, true)]);

echo $output;
```

Working [**demo**](https://3v4l.org/qCOpX).

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

Just adjust the output format before sending.

```
$output= ['image' => json_decode($data)];
```

or

```
$output= array("image" => json_decode($data));
```